# Go vendor license

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to use Hyperledger Fabric open source project and it has been [licensed](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/LICENSE) under Apache License 2.0 but while checking it's vendor license it got opencontainers/go-digest which is [licensed](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/vendor/github.com/opencontainers/go-digest/LICENSE.docs) under CC-BY-SA.

Is it safe to use fabric in production despite this vendor licenses ?

Comment: Probably should ask on law.stackexchange.com, since the `license` tag of stackoverflow say so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal licensing question and not a programming question. Legal/licensing questions are off-topic here. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

The open container initiative is a linux foundation project and the code is hosted on github under the opencontainers project. The go-digest repository has 2 licenses, 1 for the code found at https://github.com/opencontainers/go-digest/blob/master/LICENSE and the one you are looking at is the license for the documentation found at https://github.com/opencontainers/go-digest/blob/master/LICENSE.docs

Risk assessment of the licenses and the code base is something that you need to make as different people/groups/organisations have different levels of risk adverseness, however the above information should provide you with enough information to make that assessment about go-digest.